# Properties of additive function $\phi\in C^1((0,\infty))$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\phi\in C^1((0,\infty))$ and $\phi(x)+\phi(y)=\phi(xy),\forall x,y\in (0,\infty)$. Show that for $x>0$
>   
>   a)  $x\phi'(x)=\phi'(1)$
>   b)  $\phi(x)=\phi'(1)\ln(x) $

My work so far: I was able to show that $\phi(\frac{1}{x})=-\phi(x),\forall x\in(0,\infty)$ but I don't know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just differentiate w.r.t. $y$ keeping $x$ fixed. This gives $\phi'(y)=x\phi'(xy)$ by Chain Rule and putting $y=1$ gives the first part.

For the second par use 1): $\phi'(x)=\frac  c x$ where $c=\phi'(1)$. Integrating we get $\phi (x)=c\ln x+d$ where $d$ is a constant. Going back to the given equation check that $d$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to think about what differentiation is: i.e. the limit of a quotient of differences.  So you know
$$ \phi(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(x+h) - \phi(x) }{h} $$
and, as you've already observed, $\phi(1/x) = -\phi(x)$ so we can convert that difference into a sum:
$$ \phi(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(x+h) + \phi(1/x)}{h} $$
Now using the given property of $\phi$, and multiplying through by $h$ (not forgetting that the limit now applies to both sides) we get:
$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}h\phi(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \phi \left(1+(h/x) \right) $$
and so we conclude that $ 0 = \phi(1)$.

Now let's take a look at $x\phi '(x)$.  Writing the limit quotient out we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x\phi '(x) &=& \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} x\left( \frac{\phi(x+h) -\phi(x)}{h} \right) \\
{} &= & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{h} (\phi(x+h) + \phi(1/x) ) \\
{} &= & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{x}{h} \phi \left( \frac{x+h}{x} \right) 
\end{eqnarray} $$
Now we'll make a change of variable: set $k = h/x$ so that $k \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.  Then we get:
$$ x\phi '(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{k}\phi(1+k) $$
This is **almost** a limit quotient itself; if we have $\phi(1)$ in there it would be.  But... we proved above that $\phi(1)=0$ so we **do** have it!  So:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
 x\phi '(x) &=& \lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(1+k) -\phi(1)}{k} \\
{} &= & \phi '(1)
\end{eqnarray}$$

For part b) note that $\phi '(1)$ is a constant and just integrate.